# Audio spectrum, pitch shift and generic audio elaboration in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, audio, dft, spectrum, centroid

I'm writing a MATLAB program which takes the fundamental (example, la4 or A4 at 440Hz), and, after having asked to the user the frequency which frequency he/she wants, the program will produce the transposed sound. If, for example the user wants a 880Hz frequency from the original file which is 440Hz, it will double every frequency (harmonics included).

I have tried to use `MIRPitch`, which is not implemented here, but the function wasn't working anyway after having installed all the toolboxes.

How can I take the fundamental? How can I transpose it in other ways?

```
[y,Fs]=audioread("Test.wav");
[x,Fs]=audioread("LookingForHappiness.mp3");
D=0.8;
%D=(1/Fs)*length(x);
% Digital format ----------------------------------------------------------

Fs=44100;       % Sampling rate (Hz)
Ts=1/Fs;        % Sampling Period (s)



% Start DFT -------------------------------------------------------------


W=D;                % Set the window analysis to pattern duration
N=W/Ts;             % Samples in a window frame
F0=1/W;             % Fourier fundamental frequency
K=Fs*W;             % Total computable frequencies

for k=0:K-1         % k is the frequency index (f=K*F0)
    for(n=0:N-1)
        s(n+1)=sin(2*pi*k*F0*n*Ts);  % n is the time index (t=n*Ts)
        c(n+1)=cos(2*pi*k*F0*n*Ts);  % n is the time index (t=n*Ts)
    end
    Xi(k+1)=0;
    Xr(k+1)=0;
    for (n=0:N-1)
        Xi(k+1)=Xi(k+1)+x(n+1)*s(n+1);
        Xr(k+1)=Xr(k+1)+x(n+1)*c(n+1);
    end
    Xi(k+1)=Xi(k+1)/N;        % Scale by 1/N each frequency bin
    Xr(k+1)=Xr(k+1)/N;        % Scale by 1/N each frequency bin
end
Xi(1)=Xi(1)/2;                % Frequency 0 amplitude is scaled by 1/N
Xr(1)=Xr(1)/2;                % Frequency 0 amplitude is scaled by 1/N

% Show results ------------------------------------------------------------

Xa=2*sqrt(Xi.^2+Xr.^2);       % Computes amplitude spectrum

Fscale=0:F0:(Fs/2);
subplot(2,1,1);
plot(Fscale,Xa(1:K/2+1));    % Plot the amplitude spectrum
xlabel ('frequency (Hz) ')
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(x(1:2));              % Plot the signal  %era 1:100
xlabel ('time (s) ')
sound("L4A.mp3");
```

Comment: Thanks for adding an actual question, but please also mention why the code here is not working satisfactory. It now looks a bit oddly attached to the end of the post. Does it work? If not, where does it fail? Is it imprecise, does it error, does it need extension ... ?

Comment: Hi, i don't reach to configure the MIRPitch and i don't know other ways to take the fundamental.

Comment: An another problem of this program is that the second part of the code prints always the same thing.